# How do I prove that $((2-2\cos(2x))/(\cos x \sin 2x)) = ((1/(\csc x - 1)) + (1/(\csc x +1)))$?

Tags: proof-writing, induction, solution-verification

Does anyone know how to continue this proof? I am quite stuck at one point. Please note that I only have to equate one side of the equation.

$$
2-2\cos(2x)/\cos x (\sin 2x) = 1/(\csc x - 1) + 1/(\csc x +1)
$$

Here's my solution (I am equating only the left-hand side to be equal to the right-hand side):

$$
2-2(1-2 \sin^2x)/2(\cos^2x)\sin x
$$

$$
2\sin x/\cos^2x
$$

$$
2\sin x/1-\sin^2x
$$

$$
2\sin x/(1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)
$$

I am stuck at the last part. Does anyone have some tips to continue this? Thank you to those who would answer.

Comment: you can always use \frac{}{} to make the fractions look better

Comment: You should be more careful with your typesetting.  For example, is your last equation $$\frac{2 \sin x}{(1 - \sin x)(1 + \sin x)}$$ or instead $$\frac{2 \sin x}{(1 - \sin x)}(1 + \sin x) ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done. Write $\sin x = \frac{1}{\csc x}$ to get,

$\begin{align}\frac{2\sin x}{(1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)} &= \frac{\frac2{\csc x}}{(1-\frac1{\csc x})(1+\frac1{\csc x})} = \frac{2\csc x}{(\csc x-1)(\csc x+1)}\\ 
\\&=\frac{(\csc x+1)+(\csc x-1)}{(\csc x-1)(\csc x+1)} = \frac{1}{\csc x-1}+\frac{1}{\csc x+1}\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\dfrac{1}{\csc x - 1} + \dfrac{1}{\csc x + 1} = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{\sin x} - 1} + \frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{\sin x} + 1} = \dfrac{\sin x}{1 - \sin x} + \dfrac{\sin x}{1 + \sin x}$$